# Switching to GUI is not working on RHEL. How do I switch it?

Tags: user-interface, virtual-machine, virtualbox, rhel8

I created a VM of RHEL on VirtualBox using ISO. I was able to log in to the VM, but it's only operating in CLI mode. I wanna switch to GUI mode but commands are not changing the settings. Is there any other workaround for this?

I tried the following commands:
sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target